# Why the iPhone 5 has the width only of 320 pixels?

Tags: html, ios, css

I wrote a simple html markup. Here it is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                       
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
   *{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #div{
    height:91px;
    width:320px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
   }
   
   body{
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div id="div">hello</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to run it on a desktop dispaly 20" as if it is an iPhone5 using the crome devtools.

The red square width is set as 320 CSS pixels. I also wrote . **I thought that the width of the iPhone5 will be 640 pixels. Hardware pixels.** But it has only 320 pixels (**WHAT PIXELS?** A screen can not be measured in CSS pixels). The red square width (320 CSS pixels) is equal to iPhone width. I do not understand **why is it so**. I am used that my 20" display has a width of 1600 hardware pixels. And if I am writing

```js
window.screen.width
```

I am getting 1600 hardware pixels. But if I am writing

```js
window.screen.width
```

when I am emulating the iPhone5 console also says to me that the width is 320 pixels.
[image]

Comment: ios/osx LIE about their pixel resolution, to facility intra-device scaling. https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: so 320 px are 320 CSS pixels or dip or hardware pixels?

Comment: You should use 320pt in CSS instead, and read up on meta for viewport and retina.